# Splitting Bar Chart using Highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have this chart below and I need to separate the values of the Bar Chart like the image below using Highcharts

[image]

How can this be achieved using HighCharts. Thanks!

Comment: You can do a couple of things. 1) just use blank categories, and NULL data values for the empty spots; 2) use three different x axes, one for each group, each with its own category set, setting the *left* and *width* properties for each axis to achieve the desired layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, here is an example that answers the question asked, and also separates the values and growth percent into two separate plots on the same chart, removing the obfuscation of the data that is caused by plotting unrelated units together with dual y axes (obviously you can skip that part if you want, but I would strongly recommend separating these two data elements):

The category setup:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: [
    '2008', 
    '2009', 
    '2010', 
    '2011', 
    '', 
    'YTDDec2011', 
    'YTDDec2012', 
    '', 
    'MATDec2011', 
    'MATDec2012'
  ]
}
```

The data setup:

```
data: [1638, 1723, 1974, 1983, null, 1983, 2100, null, 1983, 2100]
```

And:

```
data: [0, 5.2, 14.6, 0.5, null, 0.5, 5.9, null, 0.5,5.9]
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/jwte7gmh/

Output:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I see. Nice! Thanks!